# Trying to create a custom search bar for Google Sheets but it's not woring

Tags: google-sheets

The idea to is to create a filter/search that will return results if the first condition is met or is left blank, if the second second condition is met or is left blank, if the third condition is met or is left blank.

Essentially, if any or all conditions are left blank then it will return results. My code instead returns data based on how many conditions have been set but won't return any data if one of them are left blank.

=SORT(FILTER('Video List'!B2:P161,('Video List'!E2:E161=C2),('Video List'!F2:F161=C3),('Video List'!G2:G161=C4),(REGEXMATCH('Video List'!I2:I161,C5)=FALSE),ISBETWEEN('Video List'!D2:D,C6,C7)),3,FALSE)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Please provide input and expected output